# C++ cin for loop not working as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

I have the following code:

```
vector<int> scores(3, 0);
int wow;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
    cin >> wow;
    scores.push_back(wow);
}
```

I want to store 3 `int`s read consecutively from `cin` in a `vector`. But the loop is *not* working as expected as the loop keeps on going even after reaching the condition `i < 3`.

I tried watching on Youtube about using a `for` loop and `cin` and it seems it should be working fine ([like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dM38P1x14Tw))

What is wrong with my code?

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: What is "wow" and where is it declared ?

Comment: "But the loop is not working as i expected." What did you expect?

Comment: @Caramiriel was expecting that it would only execute 3x. But it keeps running even though i reach the i < 3 condition

Comment: What does the input look like?

Comment: @Snps I updated my question and put the output image. You can see that i reach more than 3 inputs which should not be the case becase of (i<3) condition

Comment: @Tifa Should work fine. See this [live example](http://ideone.com/Bvzmjv)

Comment: @Snps hi thanks it works. I just realize the using the enter on the numeric keys is different on the main enter key. Thats why it happens.. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`push_back` add an element at the end of the vector, resizing the vector so its size is incremented. If you want to set the vector value, you need to do:

```
cin >> wow ;
scores[i] = wow ;
```

Or better :

```
cin >> scores[i] ;
```

Another way is to declare a vector with no size but it's less efficient (you resize the array at each loop):

```
vector <int> scores ;
for (...) {
    cin >> wow ;
    scores.push_back (wow) ;
}
```

Comment: +1 as you did give him both options.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But my real problem is about the looping and cin

Comment: This doesn't address the issue he is talking about. "For", as "i" is untouched.

Answer (score 5):

```
   vector<int> scores;
   int wow = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
        cout<<i<<endl;
        cin>>wow;
        scores.push_back(wow);
    }
```

should work fine.

Comment: ITs the same, it still keeps going on even if i reach the condition(i<3)

Comment: It will stop "if i >=3". Read about for loop conditions.

Comment: If you mean using the if statement inside the loop i think its pretty redundant. I already have the condition with my loop.

Comment: no i said it will stop when i >= 3 not an if statement inside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping. I just realize that the enter button in numeric keys and the enter button on alphanumeric keys are different. I always press the enter on numeric keys thats why it never returns the number I input and assume the those number I input are in the same digit so the number 3 
2 
3 
2 
3 
2 is actually 323232.